# Search for the references to a layout xml file in android code using eclipse IDE for android

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, search, reference

I am using eclipse IDE.  If I have a variable or an instance of a class.  If I select it and do Ctrl+Shift+G, I can get all the references to that variable or the class instance in that workspace.  Similarly, can I get references to an xml file in the android code using any short cut?
Lets say, I have layout xml file app_view.xml.  I need to search the android code where this xml is being referenced.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know of any shortcut, but you could just use the search menu to search in your project for occurrences of

```
R.layout.your_layout_name
```

If you copy (`ctrl + c`) in a java file the text `R.layout.your_layout_name`, you can directly use `Search => Text => Project`.

Or a less 'elegant' solution, temporary remove the xml from the project, so that you can look for compile errors in your java sources.